# Fail to start application debugging - combined C/java android application in Eclipse

Tags: java, c++, eclipse, android-ndk

NDK_LOCATION is set correctly. The ndk-build command finishes fine and I can see the library in /libs/areabi-v7a - I tried also building all platforms but the message remains. The app doesn't start with this message in eclipse console:

```
[2014-02-26 15:56:16 - fgeclient] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2014-02-26 15:56:16 - fgeclient] Android
[2014-02-26 15:56:16 - fgeclient] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2014-02-26 15:56:16 - fgeclient] NDK:
[2014-02-26 15:56:16 - fgeclient] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2014-02-26 15:56:16 - fgeclient] Could
[2014-02-26 15:56:16 - fgeclient] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2014-02-26 15:56:16 - fgeclient] not
[2014-02-26 15:56:16 - fgeclient] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2014-02-26 15:56:16 - fgeclient] find
[2014-02-26 15:56:16 - fgeclient] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2014-02-26 15:56:16 - fgeclient] platform
[2014-02-26 15:56:16 - fgeclient] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2014-02-26 15:56:16 - fgeclient] files
[2014-02-26 15:56:16 - fgeclient] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2014-02-26 15:56:16 - fgeclient] (headers
[2014-02-26 15:56:16 - fgeclient] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2014-02-26 15:56:16 - fgeclient] and
[2014-02-26 15:56:16 - fgeclient] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2014-02-26 15:56:16 - fgeclient] libraries)
[2014-02-26 15:56:16 - fgeclient] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2014-02-26 15:56:16 - fgeclient] 
[2014-02-26 15:56:16 - fgeclient] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2014-02-26 15:56:16 - fgeclient] 
[2014-02-26 15:56:16 - fgeclient] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2014-02-26 15:56:16 - fgeclient] 
[2014-02-26 15:56:16 - fgeclient] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2014-02-26 15:56:16 - fgeclient] 
Android
[2014-02-26 15:56:16 - fgeclient] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2014-02-26 15:56:16 - fgeclient] NDK:
[2014-02-26 15:56:16 - fgeclient] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2014-02-26 15:56:16 - fgeclient] Please
[2014-02-26 15:56:16 - fgeclient] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2014-02-26 15:56:16 - fgeclient] run
[2014-02-26 15:56:16 - fgeclient] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2014-02-26 15:56:16 - fgeclient] build/tools/gen-platforms.sh
[2014-02-26 15:56:16 - fgeclient] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2014-02-26 15:56:16 - fgeclient] to
[2014-02-26 15:56:16 - fgeclient] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2014-02-26 15:56:16 - fgeclient] build
[2014-02-26 15:56:16 - fgeclient] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2014-02-26 15:56:16 - fgeclient] the
[2014-02-26 15:56:16 - fgeclient] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2014-02-26 15:56:16 - fgeclient] corresponding
[2014-02-26 15:56:16 - fgeclient] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2014-02-26 15:56:16 - fgeclient] directory.
[2014-02-26 15:56:16 - fgeclient] Unable to detect application ABI's
```

Before I converted app to combined java/C++ project in eclipse I was able to run it (I was building the native part manually) though I was getting errors at native level - hence my attempt to debug it.

My environment is Win7/Cygwin.

As for suggestion to run build/tools/gen-platforms.sh - this script is used for generating debugging libraries for kernel android stuff (and that is already prebuild and included as part of ndk)

Does anyone have any suggestions how to fix it ?

I tried at home and at work with the same result (that can mean I make the same mistake twice but it can be some systematic error)

For reference I've packed my project & uploaded here - http://ulozto.cz/xQurLAUV/fgeclient-zip

[image]

Comment: could you add your make files ?

Comment: @Yuvi - I've packed the whole project.

Answer (score 0):

The logs showing here that ndk didn't find relevant ABI, Have to tried running `build/tools/gen-platforms.sh` script as prompted in logs.

Comment: I can see that; question is why and how to fix that :) as for running the script - I updated my question with what this script does.

Comment: @OndrejSvejdar could you verify your ndk path in eclipse preferences.